# How to access Windows ntfs ea/extended attributes under Linux or Windows? Or convert Volfs to DrvFs past version 1903?

Tags: linux, ntfs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ntfs-3g, windows-10-v21h1

I accidentally deregistered the legacy wsl1 install at `%APPDATA%\local\lxss` (back at the time when wsl was called bash on Ubuntu on Windows and there could be only 1 rootfs which had to be installed by bash.exe).
Fortunately for the important data, the file system was untouched.

So I installed a new wsl1 using the modern method in the hope I could recover the data by moving the `lxss` directory into the relevant `%APPDATA%\LocalPackage`. But unfortunately, `%APPDATA%\local\lxss` is using a different mapping nearer Interix where symlinks target are stored inside file data instead of [extended attributes in newer wsl1 installs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/wsl/blob/main/WSL/file-permissions.md) also supported by `ntfs-3g`.

So the best option looks like to convert the relevant extended attributes to [their newer equivalents](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/wsl/blob/main/WSL/file-permissions.md) but I have no ideas on how to access them on Windows and the [various methods listed under Linux returns nothing through ntfs-3g including on unrelated Windows system files which normally contains some of them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300168/how-do-i-get-a-dump-of-all-extended-attributes-for-a-file).

Or as an alternative, what registry keys I should use in order to reregister the legacy install again?

Comment: Beware that NTFS has _two_ kinds of "extended attributes": OS/2-like EAs and MacOS-like Alternate Data Streams (ADS). Linux xattrs via ntfs-3g are actually mapped to alternate streams (even though xattrs are more like EAs than streams) because almost nothing uses EAs, but... the way that Microsoft doc page is written, I actually can't tell which ones it's referring to: it could be a stream name but it _could_ also be an EA name.

Comment: Could you get a dump of the file information using `ntfsinfo` on the raw block device (not through a mounted filesystem)? It would show a list of all streams and other details. Windows `fsutil file layout` might also work.

Comment: @user1686 I m intersted in the undocumented attributes used by wsl1 at the beginning. And second, yes I can use `ntfsinfo` but there are 500Gib of other data with 20,000,000 files on the same drive partition.

Comment: @user1686 according to ntfs-3g those attributes are stored as ea names.

Comment: Point `ntfsinfo` at the specific path of the one file you want to see, the other 20,000,000 files are irrelevant, and please copy the output into your post.

Comment: @user1686 Ok, in older versions, they put everything into a single long hex value stored into `$LXATTRB` ea. I ve no idea on to parse it because of the lack of official documentation on the format.